# Need explicit formula for reversion of a Chern-character-like series

Tags: power-series, symmetric-functions

On the first sight this looks like homotopy theory question but actually came from need to simplify some expressions related to the [Rasch model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasch_model_estimation) from the [Item Response Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Item_response_theory).

Let
$$
s=\sum_i\frac{c_ix}{1+c_ix}=\sum_{k\geqslant1}(-1)^kp_kx^k,
$$
where $p_k=\sum_ic_i^k$ are the power sum symmetric functions of the $c_i$.

I need an explicit formula for coefficients of the reverse series (that is, expression of $x$ in terms of $s$) using those symmetric functions of the $c_i$ which would give a possibly nice outcome. Choosing elementary symmetric functions $e_k$ of the $c_i$ gives
$$
x=\frac1{e_1}s+\frac{e_1^2-2 e_2}{e_1^3}s^2+\frac{e_1^4-5 e_2 e_1^2-3 e_3 e_1+8 e_2^2}{e_1^5}s^3+\frac{e_1^6-9 e_2 e_1^4-11 e_3 e_1^3+32 e_2^2 e_1^2-4 e_4 e_1^2+30 e_2 e_3 e_1-40 e_2^3}{e_1^7}s^4+...;
$$
One could of course use the $p_k$s themselves as there are some explicit expressions of coefficients of reversions of any power series (using Lagrange inversion for example).

> What I want to know is whether some clever choice of a basis of symmetric functions (complete, Schur, Witt, I don't know) gives particularly handy expressions and whether this is related to any known nice combinatorics/geometry/...

Comment: What makes you think it's invertible? Assuming finitely many $c$'s, for a given $s$ you get a polynomial equation for $x$, which most likely has many roots.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev In my case I actually know there is a unique **real** solution which is the only thing I need. Just did not want to mix different things in the question, this one you may consider as a purely formal question.

Comment: (in fact in my case $x$ and the $c_i$ are (strictly) positive real numbers)